# Addition and Subtraction Program

Tags: java, while-loop, find, delimiter, addition

I'm relatively new to Java and I'm trying to write a program for my computer programming class that will accept a string from the user (the string must be something like 1 + 2 - 1) and then take the string, use a delimiter to get rid of the +/- signs, and then perform the addition and subtraction and return the sum of the string input. To do this, my program has to run through a while loop and each time an integer is found it must perform the appropriate function based on whether a + or - sign preceded the number. I'm trying to use .findInLine to have the program determine whether the character is a + or - and then based on this add or subtract the number that follows, but it doesn't seem to work while also using a delimiter and I'm stuck as to what to do. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Lesson17p1_ThuotteEmily
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1,257 + 137");
        String s=kb.nextLine();

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(s);
        char c=sc.findInLine("\\+").charAt(0);
        sc.useDelimiter("\\s*\\+\\s*");

        double sum=0;
        while(sc.hasNextInt());
        {
            if(c=='+')
            {
                sum=sum+sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sum is: "+sum);
   }
}
```

I had code for - signs in the program previously but deleted them temporarily because I want to figure out how to make the program run for addition problems and then I'm going to add in the subtraction programming later, using the same thing that worked for addition.

My code compiles and runs fine, but when it gets to the part where it should be adding and then returning the sum of the problem, it stops. It doesn't return an error or anything, it just freezes. I'm not really sure why this is happening. I need the delimiter for the loop and addition to work, and when I tried taking that out it returned an error. I could remove the find in line but then I'll need a different way for the program to determine whether to add or subtract and I'm struggling to think of anything. I've also tried rearranging my code so it will find the + or - sign first, then use a delimiter to get rid of the symbol and proceed with the addition or subtraction, but again the program froze.

Any help you can give is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Remade the code with comments:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class AddSubstract {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type in an expression using + and - operators.\n>> ");
    String userInput = userInputScanner.nextLine();
    // our example input: "   35 - 245 + 34982  "

    userInput = userInput.trim();
    // input is now "35 - 245 + 34982"
    if(userInput.charAt(0) != '-') userInput = "+" + userInput;
    // we need to change the input to a set of operator-number pairs
    // input is now "+35 - 245 + 34982"
    int result = 0;
    // result
    byte sign = 0;
    // sign; 1 -> positive number, -1 -> negative number, 0 -> not yet checked
    int numberToPush = 0;
    for(char c : userInput.toCharArray()) {
      if(c == '+' || c == '-') {
        if(sign == 0) sign = (c == '+')?1:-1;
        else {
          result += sign*numberToPush;
          sign = (c == '+')?1:-1;
          numberToPush = 0;
        }
      } else if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        numberToPush = ((int) c-'0') + 10*numberToPush;
      }
    }
    result += sign*numberToPush;
    System.out.println("The result is: "+result);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for offering help, but this involves things my coding class hasn't covered and I don't understand them. Sorry...